# <g:currencySelect> display only ShortName of currency.Is there any Way to include longName to this tag in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

It lists only short name of currency like USD,AUD. Is there any way to include long name too in the dropdown control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking [at the source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/6e5d1faf207d03ccdfd05a3e5e448215b4068835/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L851), you could try:

```
<g:currencySelect from="${['Euro','US Dollar','UK Pound','Swiss Franc']}" 
                  keys=${['EUR','USD','GBP','CHF']}"/>
```

Or even just bypass `currencySelect` and use a [plain `select`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html)

```
<g:select from="${['Euro','US Dollar','UK Pound','Swiss Franc']}" 
          keys=${['EUR','USD','GBP','CHF']}"/>
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the reply.  And one more doubt. this tag only displys few currency. How to get all currency in this tag

Comment: [There's a list of the ones Grails uses here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L46)

Comment: ya.Apart from that, if i want some other currency what i have to do?

Comment: Add it to the list?  It's just a list of Strings

Comment: plain select with map[longname,shortname] is useful rather than currencySelect. Is it?

Comment: `currencySelect` just wraps `select` with some default values